# How is it possible to have a non-abstract method in a class without declaring a body?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller, abstract-class

I am learning Asp.net MVC and I came to this point where a controller action calling the view() method in return section. When I clicked f12 on view() method and go to definition, I saw that this is a method in class "controller" in System.Web.Mvc namespace that has no body like many other methods of this class. But how is it possible to have a non-abstract method without a body?

`protected internal ViewResult View();`

Comment: Well, a body can be: `{}` - that's enough.

Comment: What you see is not an actual implementation of method but just a stub, basically an interface (the list of public methods).

Comment: You're looking at a class defined in another assembly, probably downloaded from nuget. VS doesn't necessarily have access to the original source code of that class, so just shows a list of non-private methods, fields and properties. You're correct in that you couldn't actually write a method like that and get it to compile -- this is just a way for VS to show the list of methods on the class

Comment: It's not showing your the actual source code of that class/method, as your VS installation has no access to the source code for that class. Hence it only shows the accessible APIs (public and protected), but not their implementations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a non abstract method with an empty body, but you can't have a non abstract method without a body at all.

This code compiles and it's an example of a method with an empty body. Notice that this is only possible if the return type is `void`.

```
// this code compiles
public class FooClass 
{
  // method with an empty body. Notice the void return type
  public void BarMethod() 
  {
  }
}
```

The following code doesn't compile and doesn't make sense too:

```
// this code does not compile
public class FooClass 
{
  // you can't have a non abstract method with no body at all
  public void BarMethod();
}
```

I think that you are being confused by the F12 key behavior inside of Visual Studio.

F12 is a shortcut for the `Go to Definition` command in Visual Studio. The `View` method is defined outside of your source code (it is part of the ASP.NET framework), so as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2022#view-metadata-as-source-code-c) the behavior of the `Go To Definition` command is showing the method metadata. That's why when you press F12 you see only the method signature and not the full method body.

As a sidenote Visual Studio has some decompiling capabilities. They are not enabled by default, but you can enable them easily. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2022#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c) documentation for the details. Once you have enabled the decompiler, you will be able to see the decompiled source code for methods defined in nuget packages and framework assemblies.

Comment: F12 doesn't decompile anything. If there is no source code, VS simple looks at the type information/metadata. (Like you would also be able to do in code with reflection. And reflection also doesn't decompile anything...)

Comment: Good point, I usually enable the Enable Navigation to Decompiled Sources option, but actually the F12 is a shortcut for Go To Definition.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace thanks for your comment, I have corrected my answer and linked the relevant documentation.